# Fundamental group of $X=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: \, z^2=x^2+y^2, \, z >0\}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Which is the fundamental group of $X=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: \, z^2=x^2+y^2, \, z >0\}$? $X$ is the cone without the vertex. Is it homotopic to $S^1$?

Comment: Yes it is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$. But we need to prove it. What are your thoughts on this, just out of interest? What is causing the doubt? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The projection along $z$ is a homeomorphism $X\cong \mathbb{R}^2-\{pt\}$. $\mathbb{R}^2-\{pt\}$ is homotopic to $S^1$. Therefore $\pi_1(X) = \mathbb{Z}$.